# ¿Cómo cálcular el tiempo promedio entre registro y registro en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito calcular un tiempo promedio entre registros de una tabla, para que la respuesta sea algo así como: `promedio = 1 hora 22 minutos`

```
| Mensaje   | Fecha de creacion   |
|-----------|---------------------|
| Hola      | 2020-05-01 13:13:54 |
| Adios     | 2020-05-01 13:13:58 |
| Hola      | 2020-05-01 13:14:01 |
| Hola      | 2020-05-02 20:13:51 |
| Adios     | 2020-05-02 20:13:58 |
| Hola      | 2020-05-02 20:14:24 |
```

Esta información la obtengo de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SELECT mensaje, fecha_creacion FROM mensajes WHERE usuario = 58;
```

Comment: Y cómo sabes cuál `Adios` corresponde a cuál `Hola`?

Comment: Son mensajes de ejemplo, no tienen relación entre sí.

Comment: Y cuál es entonces el criterio a seguir para identificar un intervalo y poderles calcular el promedio?

Comment: Puedo ordenarlas por fecha si es a lo que te refieres. Pero sería el promedio de todos los mensajes, así sean dos o sean 10000, Lo que pensé es que podría tomar el primer mensaje, el último, calcular la diferencia con datediff y al resultado dividirlo entre el numero total de mensajes.

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitás entonces, es saber el promedio de tiempo entre registro y registro, sin importar que sean mil Hola y tres Adios en toda la tabla?

Comment: Asi es, porque como digo. "Hola" y "Adios" son de ejemplo, pero son cadenas de texto. En si necesito una diferencia promedio entre registro y registro.

Comment: Esto te daría el horario promedio;

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(fecha_creacion))) as Promedio from mensajes;

Comment: horario promedio no tiene nada que ver con el promedio entre registros....

Comment: Necesitas la diferencia promedio entre los registros ordenados ascendentes por fecha. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Así es @Alfabravo

Comment: No entiendo cómo se llega a la hora con 22 minutos. Según mis cálculos, han pasado poco más de 31 horas entre el primero y el último registro, si son siete registros, eso da como promedio unas 4 horas y 25 minutos entre cada mensaje. Creo que sería bueno que expliques cómo calculas ese promedio.

Comment: Ah lo siento, eso fue de ejemplo. Para explicar lo que quiero obtener del query.

Comment: QUé versión de mysql usas?

Comment: akko, entonces, sigo sin entender lo que quieres obtener. Los datos de ejemplo debieran ser consistentes entre si.

Answer (score 0):

Para MySQL anterior a 8.0, que no hay CTE y algunas otras cosas, habría que armar una relación entre la tabla y sí misma.

Creé esta tabla de ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensajes` (
  `mensaje` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_crea` DATETIME NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `mensajes` (`mensaje`, `fecha_crea`) VALUES
  ('3 Ah', NOW()),
  ('1 Eh', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 HOUR)),
  ('4 Uh!', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)),
  ('2 Oh.', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR));
```

La consulta sugerida sería algo así:

```sql
SET @row_number = 0; 
SET @row_number2 = 0; 

SELECT *, 
abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, ms1.fecha_crea, ms2.fecha_crea)) as tsdiff_min,
abs(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, ms1.fecha_crea, ms2.fecha_crea)) as tsdiff_sec
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS `num`,
  `mensajes`.*
  FROM `mensajes`
  ORDER BY `fecha_crea` ASC
) ms1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
  *,
  (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS num2
  FROM `mensajes`
  ORDER BY `fecha_crea` ASC
  ) ms2 
ON ms1.`num` = (`num2` + 1)
ORDER BY ms1.num ASC;
```

Las variables `row_numberx` emulan un rownum del resultado de cada subconsulta.

El inner join une el registro con el inmediatamente anterior. El resultado es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las diferencias se representan como valores absolutos.

En el select exterior pongo varios ejemplos de cómo representar las diferencias entre fechas. Ya con este resultSet, podrías armar una consulta que calcule el AVG de la columna con el formato que elijas y tendrías el valor que buscas.